# run a project of another project of the same solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have 2 projects, both on the same solution.

Project#1: does a single action based on debug inputs.
           for simplicity let say that the main prints the debug inputs.

Project#2: I want to run Project#1 with for loop that run over different debug 
           inputs.

How can I do this right and efficient?
from what I understand, calling Project#1 exe file from Project#2 is not recommended. any other way to run Project#1 ::main, without changing Project#1? with only changes in Project#2 ..

Thanks,

New to advanced c++.

Comment: look into making project #1 a static library. Then project#2 will use that library.

Comment: Project#2 sounds like a job for a shell script

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do it in separate projects, you can do all from a single one, with different command line options.

for option one you can run the command line as: `pro.exe debug-print1` 
the project just print the arguments and exit.

for the second option you can create a file,
You can put all your debug prints in file, and iterate on each line from the file, you just need to mark it as a file for example with a `-f filename`.

Next step is to process multiple files or debug-prints, or combination of files and prints in the same run.

So consider the following code for example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//process a line function:
void proccess_debug_line(const std::string& debug_line)
{
    std::cout<<debug_line<<std::endl;
}
//process file by processing each line:
void process_debug_file(const std::string& debug_file_name)
{
    std::string debug_line;
    std::ifstream inputfile(debug_file_name);
    if(!inputfile)
    {
        std::cerr<<"error openning file: "<< debug_file_name <<std::endl;    
    }
    while(std::getline(inputfile, debug_line))
    {
        //use the process line
        proccess_debug_line(debug_line); 
    }
}
//argument can be a line, or a file if there is -f  before it.
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        std::string param = argv[i];
        if(param[0] == '-')
        {
            if(param == "-f") // arguments in form -f filename
            {
                if(i == argc-1 ) // -f is last arg
                {
                    std::cerr<<"Missing argument for " << param << " option."<<std::endl;
                }
                else //-f filename
                {
                    std::string filename = argv[++i];
                    process_debug_file(filename);
                }
            }
            else if(param.substr(0,2)== "-f")// argument in form -ffilename can be legal too
            {
                std::string filename = &(argv[i][2]);
                process_debug_file(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr<<"Unknown option '" << param << "'"<<std::endl;
                ++i;
            }
        }
        else //a 'regular' parameter (without -f before it) is a debug print
        {
            proccess_debug_line(param);
        }
    }
}
```